# fontawesome icon in react-native with xcode not showing

Tags: xcode, react-native, font-awesome

In Android system, all icons are showing normally. But in TestFlight on ios, the icons showing like image below;

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2RU0.png)

edit:
the mentioned code:

```
<Card borderRadius={25}>
                <View style={{marginBottom: 15}}>
                        <Input
                          placeholder="Email"
                          onChangeText={login => setLogin({ login })}
                          value={login}
                          inputStyle={{ marginLeft: 10, color: 'black' }}
                          containerStyle={{ width: '100%' }}
                          keyboardType="email-address"
                          returnKeyType="next"
                          autoCorrect={false}
                          leftIcon={
                          <Icon
                              name="envelope"
                              type="font-awesome"
                              color="#00A2BC"                    
                              size={20}
                          />
                        }/>
                </View>
 </Card>
```

I am using

import { Icon }  from 'react-native-elements';

i installed the app using TestFlight on iphone ios.

Comment: Can we see some code ?